# How to identify figure or subplot by string or variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I liked how `imshow` behaves in OpenCV: if you ask to show image in window with given name, and this name exists, then it redraws this window, and if this named window does not exist yet, then it creates it.

Is it possible to simulate this behavior with figures in Matlab?

If I write

```
if ishandle(spectrum)
   figure(spectrum);
else
   spectrum = figure();
end
```

I getting an error if spectrum variable not defined at first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the spectrum variable exists before checking whether it is a handle:

```
if exist('spectrum', 'var') && ishandle(spectrum)
   figure(spectrum);
else
   spectrum = figure();
end
```

Or, before ever assigning spectrum to a figure handle, you can assign it to a dummy value (e.g. nan). Thus, when it get's to your *if* branch, it already has a value and Matlab won't throw an error:

```
spectrum = nan;

% ... stuff happens, maybe even a while or for loop ...

if ishandle(spectrum)
   figure(spectrum);
else
   spectrum = figure();
end
```